# Permission Error in NGINX and Gunicorn in Docker: connect() to unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream

Tags: python, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Python Flask app run with Gunicorn, NGINX, and Docker compose.  I'm getting the following error when submitting an HTTP POST.  I'm running this on a Linux Mint host.

```
nginx_1   | 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2019:20:49:47 +0000] "GET /v1/simulations HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.18.0"
nginx_1   | 2019/10/18 20:49:47 [crit] 6#6: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /v1/simulations HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock:/v1/simulations", host: "localhost:5000"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: grip-server_server
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        GRIP_ENVSET: ${GRIP_ENV}
    volumes:
      - ".:/gripcode"
      - "/tmp:/tmp"
      # Mount the Docker socket so that other Docker images can be started up.
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/tmp/gunicorn.sock:/tmp/gunicorn.sock"
    environment:
      - PORT=5005
      - GRIP_ENV=${GRIP_ENV}
      - JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES=${JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES}
      - JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES=${JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES}
      - DOCKER_HOST=${DOCKER_HOST}
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - celery
      - nginx
    # Listening on port 5005
  nginx:
    # restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "5000:5005"
    volumes:
       # - .:/www/static
       # - web-data:gripcode
      - ".:/gripcode"
      - "/tmp:/tmp"
      - "/tmp/gunicorn.sock:/tmp/gunicorn.sock"
    network_mode: host
    # Listening on port 5000
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: redis
    network_mode: host
    # Listening on 6379
  #rabbitmq:
  #  image: rabbitmq:3
  #  restart: on-failure
  #  container_name: redis
  #  network_mode: host
  #  # Listening on 5672 and 15672
  #  #environment:
  #    #- redis_DEFAULT_USER=user
  #    #- redis_DEFAULT_PASS=password
  celery:
    image: grip-server_celery
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    command: bash -c "bash ./bin/wait_for_broker.sh && bash ./bin/fix_celery_naming.sh && celery -E -A components.grip_sim_api_server.server.celery worker --pool gevent" # Debugging: -l debug
    volumes:
      - .:/gripcode
      - "/tmp:/tmp"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" # To be able to start the GridLAB-D docker image
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://127.0.0.1:6379
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://127.0.0.1:6379
      #- CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672
      #- CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=amqp://localhost
      - DOCKER_HOST=${DOCKER_HOST}
      - DEBUG_CELERY=${DEBUG_CELERY} # True to enable remote debugging
      - CELERY_RDB_PORT=${CELERY_RDB_PORT}
    tty: true
  omf:
    image: presence/omf:latest
    restart: on-failure
    #build:
    #  context: .
    #  args:
    #    GRIP_ENVSET: ${GRIP_ENV}
    working_dir: /home/omf/omf/scratch/GRIP
    command: grip.py
    network_mode: host
    # Listening on port 5100
  flower:
    #image: mher/flower
    image: grip-server_flower
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    command: bash -c "bash ./bin/wait_for_broker.sh && flower -A components.grip_sim_api_server.server.celery worker --address=0.0.0.0 --port=5555 --logging=debug --pool gevent"
    working_dir: /gripcode
    volumes:
      - .:/gripcode
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - celery
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://127.0.0.1:6379
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://127.0.0.1:6379
      #- CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672
      #- CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672
    network_mode: host
    # Listening on port 5555
    network_mode: host
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM library/python:3.7-stretch


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip \
    postgresql-client \
    # TODO - Might not need this any longer with GridLAB-D on its own container
    # GridLAB-D requires this library
    # libxerces-c-dev \
    # For VIM
    apt-file  \
    vim \
    #for Docker (spin up another Docker container sibling from inside this container)
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    software-properties-common \
    #python3-distutils
    python-distutils-extra

#RUN yes | apt-get install rabbitmq-server

# Install Docker, to be able to run sibling docker containers
RUN add-apt-repository \
```

./nginx/Dockerfile:

```
#FROM tutum/nginx
FROM nginx:1.17.4

#RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
#COPY sites-enabled/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx

# RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx
RUN chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /etc/nginx
```

./nginx/nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

user nobody nogroup;
# 'user nobody nobody;' for systems with 'nobody' as a group instead
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # set to 'on' if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # 'use epoll;' to enable for Linux 2.6+
  # 'use kqueue;' to enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
  sendfile on;

  upstream app_server {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response

    # for UNIX domain socket setups
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

    # for a TCP configuration
    # server 192.168.0.7:8000 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  #server {
  #  # if no Host match, close the connection to prevent host spoofing
  #  listen 80 default_server;
  #  return 444;
  #}

  server {
    # use 'listen 80 deferred;' for Linux
    # use 'listen 80 accept_filter=httpready;' for FreeBSD
    listen 5000;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    # set the correct host(s) for your site
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    # root /path/to/app/current/public;

    location / {
      # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    # error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    # location = /500.html {
    #  root /path/to/app/current/public;
    #}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had configured both port binding ("5000:5005") and host networking in the main Docker compose file.  The way I got things to work on the Mac was to remove the port binding in the main file, just keep the host networking in the main file, and then in the Mac Docker Compose override file override the host networking with the default bridge networking, then add in the port binding in the Mac override Docker Compose file.

The other problem was that I was trying to do this mapping of port 5000 to port 5005 in Docker Compose, but that's actually the responsibility of the NGINX configuration.  All I needed to do in Docker was to expose the ports for NGINX and the Flask/Gunicorn app.  This was done implicitly with host networking in the main file (5000:5000 since I was using a non-default NGINX port)  and explicitly in the Mac Docker Compose override file using port binding (5005:5005 for Gunicorn/Flask, also non-default port).  Then NGINX itself reversed proxied from 5000 (NGINX) to 5005 (Gunicorn) based on the NGINX configuration.  This was across Docker containers.

Comment: Can you explain more? My error is "gunicorn.sock failed no such file or directory"